# DC motor gets stuck when it hits the end of its track

Tags: dc-motor

EDIT: Solved, I'm not sure how to mark it as solved though

I don't really know what this phenomenon is called so if this question has been asked before I apologize.

Basically I have a dc motor and it has a "finger". When the motor spins it reaches a switch that stops the motor and presses it. Afterwards the motor is supposed to reverse. However, it gets stuck?? I don't even know what its getting stuck on, I have to spin it manually for it to reverse. This happens when it encounters any barrier - like a wall for example. I have no idea what even is causing it to not spin, is it something to do with its internals locking in because of it continuing to spin after the switch stops it?

The motor spins a worm gear that spins a normal gear that the finger is attached to.

Comment: Yes, the momentum of the spinning rotor is enough energy to lock up the worm drive even after power is removed, to the point where the motor's torque is not sufficient to unlock it. You need to find either an electrical way or a mechanical way to keep that from happening.

Comment: I see, so that is why it locks up. I made an electrical thing with diodes that significantly reduces the spin of the motor after it hits the switch, I guess I will look into a mechanical way.

Comment: The way to mark a question as "solved" is to click the tick mark next to the answer that solves it. If you solved it by yourself, write your own answer explaining how you solved it, then click the tick mark next to that. Make sure your own answer is useful for other people who have the same problem.

Comment: Since worm gears involve sliding motion, you may find the correct lubricant helps.

Comment: "*I'm not sure how to mark it as solved though.*" Write a short answer to explain how you solved it and then you can accept your own answer to indicate that it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem with the worm gear "locking up". The only way around it is either to hit the motor with a large voltage pulse (current) to unlock the worm gear, or try for a mechanical solution.